# layoutSubviews Confusion — Manipulating TMQuiltView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, layoutsubviews

I'm trying out this custom class — TMQuiltView — https://github.com/1000Memories/TMQuiltView. Normally, I layout interfaces in Storyboard, and that's not an issue. Since this is a custom class, it appears as if I have to do so programatically.

I would have posted a screenshot of what comes in their demo, but I don't have enough reputation. Instead, I will show the -(void) layoutSubviews method

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

self.photoView.frame = CGRectInset(self.bounds, kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin, kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin);
self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin, self.bounds.size.height - 20 - kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin, self.bounds.size.width - 2 * kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin, 20);

}
```

My goal is to get that titleLabel to appear below the photoView, but I don't want it to be a definite size (i.e. I would have used autolayout if I were storyboarding). So, in the titleLabel's method, I tried to calculate the height of the label:

```
CGSize labelSize = [_titleLabel.text sizeWithFont:_titleLabel.font
                                constrainedToSize:_titleLabel.frame.size
                                    lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    labelHeight = labelSize.height;
```

But here's where I'm running into a dead-end. I can't use this in making a CGRect (CGPoint is incompatible). Do I make a CGRect for the image somewhere? How do I define it in relation to self.bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't forget to call `[super layoutSubviews];` in `layoutSubviews` method.
2. `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` is deprecated in iOS8
3. you can use `_titleLabel.lineBreakMode` in your calculating method

Ofc you can use this size in your method eg via:

```
CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, size.width, size.height);
```

To help you to code it I need to clarify: You want to have an imageView which is above label and the label should resize depending on text size?

Ad3. You can use such method instead (source: [GitHub opensource library](https://github.com/natalia-osa/DrawCircleFrame/blob/master/DrawCircleFrame/DrawCircleFrame/NSString%2BSize.m)):

```
- (CGSize)ios67sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize textSize;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:)]) {
        textSize = [self boundingRectWithSize:size options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil].size;
    } else {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        textSize = [self sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    }

    return textSize;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's suppose that textSize is defined. How do I create the proper rectangles. For the imageView there is  CGRectInset(self.bounds, kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin, kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin); What about the titleLabel? CGRectMake(kTMPhotoQuiltMargin, bottom of image + 2, size.width, size.height)? How do I get bottom of image?

Comment: `CGRect imageViewRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin, kTMPhotoQuiltViewMargin);` `CGRect titleLabelRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(imageViewRect), CGRectGetMaxY(imageViewRect) + myMargin, textSize.width, textSize.height);`

Comment: Alright. I seem to be getting there. I will keep playing until I get the results I want, but your answer has helped in the meantime. Thanks!